# button is not responsive in relate to parallel buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using the following code to put 3 button next to  each other and this is working 
Ok when I use it like following, **but** the problem is when I reduce the size of browser page slowly the detailes button is become on top the delete button,
the edit and delete are not changing,how can I make also the details button to be responsive?

```
  @if (ViewBag.condition)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }) |
        </td>
        <td style="position:relative; right: 60px ">@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })</td>
    }
    else
    {
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })</td>
    }
```

Comment: dont use tables in the first place! please!

Comment: @vlrprbttst they might be putting buttons inside a table for a reason...

Comment: @vlrprbttst-The button is for each row in the table...

Comment: @shopiaT What does the rest of your table look like and which bootstrap styles are you adding to it?

Comment: The overlap is caused due to your use of `position: relative;` style.

Comment: @Grapho-I use the class="table"

Comment: @rageit-yes I know that but how should I change it to solve the responsive problem

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot of code to work with, and I don't know much about bootstrap. But typically on mobile devices I set td's display to block. However your doctype declaration can determine whether or not that will work (I belive you have to be in standards mode). Try adding this to your CSS and/or media query if you have access to it:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

    td{
         display: block; /* or inline-block */
    }

}
```

You could alternatively test with inline style on your td elements by adding:

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

Good luck!